# Alien craft design - Would it work?

Tags: aliens, ufo

Popular visualisations of UFO crafts are mostly disc shaped like the following

[image: Disc Shaped UFO]

Would a craft like this be able to fly? Why would this shape become popular, If a species could travel the distance between planets they would need an efficient craft, Which it seems this shaped craft would not be.

Comment: http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?release=2014-154

Comment: _"Why would this shape become popular"_ I would love to read about why this shape became popular in sci-fi, but it seems off-topic to speculate.

Comment: @DrewDormann According to Donald Menzel, the term "flying saucer" first was mentioned in '47 (i.e., see here http://www.livescience.com/33351-flying-saucers-turn-64-look-back-origins-ufos.html) and the traditional shape followed on, although in reality most of these "objects" are not very saucer-like. I highly recommend his book "Flying Saucers", which is very well written and fun to read. One of the books which inspired me to get into physics when I was in high school.

Comment: If we accept the premise that these are aliens from another planet with technology far superior to our own, we have to accept that our feeble understanding of physics is inadequate to explain the shape. There can be no answer. If we don't accept the premise, this question belongs on Scifi.SE.

Comment: Why would you need an "efficient" shape for _traveling through vacuum?_ There's no aerodynamics in space.

Comment: @BrianS but you need aerodynamics if you're going to land and abduct americans.

Comment: Saucer shaped aircraft have been built and flown, so it's not much of a question... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Canada_VZ-9_Avrocar

Comment: @exussum - The craft like these can fly, because of its anti-gravity engine. These are short-distance crafts (Earth-Moon), not to other planets (as the journey is too long). This could be more on-topic on [Aliens](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80090/aliens).

Answer (score 8):

According to Donald Menzel (he is the earliest source of this information I know of), the term "flying saucer" first was mentioned in '47 and the traditional shape followed on, although in reality most of these "objects" are not very saucer-like. Here is some write-up on this story I found [here](http://www.livescience.com/33351-flying-saucers-turn-64-look-back-origins-ufos.html):

> On June 24, 1947, an amateur pilot named Kenneth Arnold was flying a
>   small plane near Mount Rainier in Washington state when he saw
>   something extraordinarily strange. Directly to his left, about 20 to
>   25 miles north of him and at the same altitude, a chain of nine
>   objects shot across the sky, glinting in the sun as they traveled.
>
> By comparing their size to that of a distant airplane, Arnold gauged
>   the objects to be about 45 to 50 feet wide. They flew between two
>   mountains spaced 50 miles apart in just 1 minute, 42 seconds, he
>   observed, implying an astonishing speed of 1,700 miles per hour, or
>   three times faster than any manned aircraft of the era. However, as if
>   controlled, the flying objects seemed to dip and swerve around
>   obstacles in the terrain.

---

> Arnold's sighting was "such a sensation that it made front page news
>   across the nation," UFO-logist and author Martin Kottmeyer wrote in an
>   article ("The Saucer Error," REALL News, 1993).
>
> "Soon everyone was looking for these new aircraft which according to
>   the papers were saucer-like in shape," Kottmeyer continued. "Within
>   weeks hundreds of reports of these flying saucers were made across the
>   nation. While people presumably thought they were seeing the same
>   things that Kenneth Arnold saw, there was a major irony that nobody at
>   the time realized. Kenneth Arnold hadn't reported seeing flying
>   saucers."
>
> In fact, Arnold had told the press that the objects had flown
>   erratically, "like a saucer if you skip it across the water." They
>   were thin and flat when viewed on edge, he said, but crescent-shaped
>   when viewed from the top down as they turned. Nonetheless, a reporter
>   named Bill Bequette of the United Press interpreted Arnold's statement
>   to mean that the objects he saw were round discs. According to
>   Benjamin Radford, UFO expert and deputy editor of the Skeptical
>   Inquirer, "It was one of the most significant reporter misquotes in
>   history."
>
> "The phrase 'flying saucers' provided the mold which shaped the UFO
>   myth at its beginning," Kottmeyer wrote. UFOs took the form of flying
>   saucers, he noted, in artist's renderings, hoax photos, sci-fi films,
>   TV shows and even the vast majority of alien abduction and sighting
>   reports for the rest of modern history, up until the present day.

This story is described in Menzel's book "[Flying Saucers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BIU1AU)", and he claims that there is no mention of such objects before that incident. Therefore, there is no sense in trying to explain the shape, as it was not caused by logic, but rather by pure accident of the craze starting with this term spread through media.

Comment: I've got the book somewhere in my garage, but it is in Russian. If someone has it at hand, feel free to find the sources he references, if any, or the original story.

Comment: And since it is not in the article, Menzel explains the phenomenon as horizontal snow twisters caused by air blowing up the slope of the mountains.

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: "Why would this shape become popular, If a species could travel the distance between planets they would need an efficient craft, Which it seems this shaped craft would not be." - OP's premise is that it is designed by sci-fi authors to endure long-distance travel, I'm showing that this premise is wrong.

Comment: @sashkello - Nice answer.  You might want to bold sections of the quote to highlight the point, though.